# angular routes with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm going through the Pro Angular tutorial.  I have a question about resolving rails routes with angular routes.

I have the following code:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/products");

$stateProvider
.state('root', {
  url: "/stores",
  abstract: true,
  template: '<ui-view/>'
})
.state('products', {
  url: "/products",
  templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('store/templates/productList.html') %>",
  controller: "productListCtrl as plCtrl"
})
.state('checkout', {
  url: "/checkout",
  templateUrl: "<%= asset_path('store/templates/checkoutSummary.html') %>"
})
```

When I go to localhost:3000 my url automatically goes to /products and displays the correct page.  However, when I hit reload on my browser I get a rails error page saying that missing template products/index.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :stores, only: :index
get 'stores/*app', to: 'stores#index'

resources :products, only: :index

namespace :api, constraints: {format: :json}, defaults: {format: :json} do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :products
  end
end

root 'stores#index'
```

**app/views/stores/index.html.slim**

```
base href="/stores"

div ng-app="storeApp"
  ui-view autoscroll="top"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server is willing to handle the routing but you deferred the task to the client.

So you should always render the base template from the server and let the client handle the routing itself.

At the end of your `routes.rb`, add:

```
  get  '*a', to: 'stores#index'
```

where `your_controller` and `your_action` match what you use for `root_path`

Comment: I edited my post, do users who answer normally get a notice?

Comment: I dont understand your question, did you try my solution?

Comment: I have the following `get 'stores/*app', to: 'stores#index'`